# TreeNode Forms to WPF conversion

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, treeview

I have been given the task of converting a forms application to WPF.  The application used `TreeNode` which is from `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView`.  I know WPF has `TreeView` but I can't find `TreeNode` is there a direct conversion for it from Forms to WPF?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is [TreeViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.aspx).

Comment: I would like to add that this is the best conversion we have but, the functionality is not exact.  Or I should say the way you go about doing things isn't the same but has more or less the same outcome.

Answer (score 19):

`TreeNode` has been replaced with `TreeViewItem`.

`TreeNode.Text` is equivalent to `TreeViewItem.Header`

`TreeNode.Nodes` is equivalent to `TreeViewItem.Items`

Comment: I hope you could upvote this so I can give answers again. Thanks.

Comment: This is awsome!